# Crazy errors with FsLex and FsYacc

Tags: f#, compiler-errors, powerpacks, fsyacc, fslex

I am trying to compile this project:

http://ramon.org.il/Here.zip

But I get a bunch of non-sense errors. They got text I am familiar with, but in the position there is nothing like that (like unexpected ')' at an empty row).

Help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many small mistake, I didn't understand at all how it works.

The bracket Tomas found was one of the mistakes (a typo), but the whole concept was wrong.

Solved now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the error message (at least the first one I checked) is on a correct line (but an invalid column on that line). I'd think that this is a by-design limitation, but I'm not 100% sure.

Anyway, line 25 of the file `LispParser.fsy` looks suspicious to me:

```
25: ExprList: Expr { List($1, -1, Null) ] }
26:         | Expr ExprList { List($1, -1, $2) }
```

The expression in curly braces is `List($1, -1, Null) ]` and there is a closing square bracket `]` but not an opening one. So, I think the bracket probably shouldn't be there. I didn't try it, but I think that the remaining errors are just consequence of this issue.

Comment: These brackets are wrong, yes.
I'm right now rushing out, but from a quick re-build there are still errors, maybe they are simple.
Will report when I come back home.